# Getting Positive Solutions Basis to Homogenous Linear Equations

Tags: python, linear-algebra, linear-programming

So I have a set of linear homogeneous equations Ax=0. I would like to solve this for non-negative solutions. I can solve the system in general and I get  the two vectors that span the solution space, but one of the vectors has negative entries. I would like to restrict the solution space to non-negative real solutions. I should add that the vector x is a vector of symbolic variables (Sympy), not sure if this is important.

I have been told that one way to do this is to use the simplex method of linear programming and set the objective function to be the zero function. When I do this in SciPy with linprog() I only get one solution vector and not the two I want (the output seems to be the sum of the two I want). I think Sage has what I am looking for, but I am wondering if I can do this just in Python. I might just have to try and call Sage with a script if this is not possible with just Python.

**Example**
Let's say I have the system:

1. x_0 - x_3 = 0
2. x_1 + x_4 - x_0 = 0
3. x_2 - x_1 = 0
4. x_3 - x_2 - x_4 = 0

Solving this system is equivalent to finding the nullspace of,

- [[1  0  0 -1  0]
- [-1 1  0  0  1]
- [0 -1  1  0  0]
- [0  0 -1  1 -1]]

So far I have tried to use the linear programming function in Scipy with the simplex method by setting the objective function to the zero function. The output there is, 
 [2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
This is the sum of the two I want. The least-squares method gives almost the same result under bounds (1,2).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sci
from scipy.optimize import linprog
from scipy.optimize import lsq_linear

A =  [  [ 1,  0,  0, -1,  0],
            [-1,  1,  0,  0,  1],
            [ 0, -1,  1,  0,  0],
            [ 0 , 0, -1,  1, -1],   ]

sol1 = linprog([0 for i in range(5)], A_eq=A, b_eq=[0 for i in range(4)], bounds=(1,None), method = 'simplex')
print('\n', "Simplex:", '\n', sol1.x, '\n   ')

sol2 = lsq_linear(np.array(A), [0 for i in range(4)], bounds = (1,2))
print("Least-squares: ", '\n', sol2.x)
```

Using Sympy's nullspace method is close as it returns a basis for the nullspace as,
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0] , [0, -1, -1, 0, 1]

I would like a basis for the subspace of the nullspace that lies in the non-negative part of Euclidean space. I believe the two vectors that span the solution space restricted to the positive reals is,
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0] , [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

Comment: @harold I'm so sorry for you guys. I just edited it as best as my non-Latex formatting abilities could.

Comment: [A version of this question on Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/33123/20688).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been asked on another site.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why not add the additional constraints `xi>=0` to the linear programming approach?

Comment: @KarstenW. Sorry. I probably should've mentioned that, but in my attempt with Scipy I did that, but I just get that one solution. The argument bounds = (1, None) is for that.

Comment: I think there are many possible solutions. You can add `x(i)>=0` and `sum(i,x(i))=1`, but then there are still many solutions (I believe the rows of A are not independent).